# How to set a variable from a text view and displaying it on a label

Tags: uitextfield, uilabel, assign

In my .h file I have set properties for both the text field and the label:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phoneNumberEntry;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;
```

I also synthesized them in the .m file:

```
@synthesize phoneNumberEntry;
@synthesize testLabel;
```

how would I save the content of the textview to a variable, and then display it to a label?

Answer (score 0):

WHat you need to do is create a string variable to hold the text of the UITextField.

```
NSString *textString = phoneNumberEntry.text;
```

then all you have to do is set the text of the label using the string variable just created

```
testLabel.text = textString;
```

EDIT:
If you're having trouble hooking it up in IB, just go to the files owner, and then click on the identity inspector, and find the box that says "class:" or something similar. THis is where you're going to type in your class. Once typed in, just hit enter, and then go to the  connections inspector. This will allow you to see the properties you have created in your .h file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It cant find phoneNumberEntry or testLabel for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:
1). You need to put one UIButton and on button action event you may save textview value like:

`- (IBAction)btnSaveClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    strTextViewVal = txtTextView.text;
}`

or you may save textview value in its delegate like this:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```